# how to monitor checkbox status with prechecked checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, forms, checkbox

This is my checkbox, which should be checked by default

```
<input type="checkbox" name="noILN-GLN" id="noILN-GLN" checked="checked" />
```

I now want an event to fire when the checkbox changes and then do this (checked) or that (not checked). This is always returns "checked":

```
$('#noILN-GLN').bind('change', function() {
     if ( $(this).attr('checked') ) {
         console.log("checked")
         } else { 
            console.log("not checked");
            }
      });
```

What do I have to change to make the console tell me if the box is checked or not? It needs to be checked by default, so I'm setting checked="checked". Any other way to pre-check the box, that might help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#noILN-GLN').bind('change', function() {
     if (this.checked) {
         console.log("checked")
         } else { 
            console.log("not checked");
            }
      });
```

Comment: @frequent You could also do `$(this).prop('checked')`. You don't need the attribute, you need the property.

Comment: @frequent In most cases `this.checked` is great. I only mentioned `prop` because that is for live properties while `attr` is for the HTML attributes on the given element.